# How to assign value in two dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays

How to assign value in two dimensional array in c#

My Code is

```
int[,] matarix = new int[4, 5];

        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
            {
                matarix[x, y] = x+"-"+y;
            }
        }
```

i tried above code but its showing error "can't implicitly convert string to int" 
How to do it ? Thanks

Comment: You are in right way. What do you want to assing it? Just assign an integer value like `matarix[x, y] = 5;`

Comment: Well what value do you want to assign to each cell? It's not really clear what you're asking here, given that you've got everything apart from the value...

Comment: `x+"-"+y` is a string.  Your `matarix` is an array of int.  Do you want an array of string, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. Just assign a value.

```
int[,] matarix = new int[4, 5];

for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
        matarix[x, y] = VALUE_HERE;
    }
}
```

One recommendation I would make, would be to use `Array.GetLength` instead of hard coding your `for` loops. Your code would become:

```
int[,] matarix = new int[4, 5];

for (int x = 0; x < matarix.GetLength(0); x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < matarix.GetLength(1); y++) {
        matarix[x, y] = VALUE_HERE;
    }
}
```

You pass in one of the array's dimensions, and it tells you how many indices exist for that dimension.

Answer (score 1):

This is a template I usually use for filling up two dimensional arrays.
Its one line and easy to change.

```
        int[,] Foo = new int[4,5];
        for(int i=0;i < Foo.Length; i++, Foo[i % Foo.GetLength(0),i / Foo.GetLength(1)] = 0; // Or value to assign
```

Also please do note that your array is holding integers while you are giving it strings (the "" converts it to a string, while x - y keeps it integer)
Hope it helps